# Keep constant margin based on vw

Tags: css, responsive-design

How can I give margin to `#more` so it will be always at the same distance from `#logo` when resizing the window?

Look at the code down here in fullscreen and resize the window you'll see that the distance from 1 to 2 changes.

Thanks for the help.

```css
body {
  font-size: 5vw;
  font-family: Arial;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
#logo {
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  position: fixed;
}
#more {
  top: 10px;
  left: 50px;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id=logo>1</div>
<div id=more>23456789</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the same unit you use for your font-size: which is `vh`.

2 important side notes:

- dont use position: fixed if you want to really be responsive
- don't use id's in css, you are not allowed re-use these in html.

```css
body {
  font-size: 5vw;
  font-family: Arial;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
#logo {
  display:inline;
}
#more {
  display:inline;
  padding-left: 2vw;
}
```

```html
<div id=logo>1</div>
<div id=more>23456789</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @JoelHarkes! Am I allowed to use position:absolute? I really need some positioning for those elements.

Comment: Yes of course you can use absolute. but know word wrap wont be applied.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I can `float:left` both div and it works aswell.

```css
body {
  font-size: 5vw;
  font-family: Arial;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
#logo,#more {
float:left;
}
```

```html
<div id=logo>1</div>
<div id=more>23456789</div>
```